# Most efficient way for an object to remove itself from a list

Tags: java, list

Let's say we have an array list of objects `ObjArray`.

What is the most efficient way for that object to locate itself within the list, and remove itself from the list?

The way I tend to use is this:

- Every object in the list has an ID that corresponds to its place in the list
- When `object.remove()` is called, the object simply simply calls `ObjArray.remove(ID)`.
- `ObjArray` is parsed from index ID upwards calling `ObjArray.get(i).ID`--. This sets all objects above the removed object to the right ID.

The other method is of course simply parsing `ObjArray` until a object match is found.

So, is there a better way of doing this? `ArrayList` is not necessary, if a `HashMap` or `LinkedList` can be used to do things better, that's just as good.

---

More information as requested.

Objects contain information as to where they need to be drawn on screen, and what image is to be drawn. The `paint` function of the main JPanel is called by a timer. The `paint` function loops through the list `ObjArray` and calls the the object's draw function (`Obj.draw(Graphics g)`).

Objects may be added or removed by clicking.

When an object is removed, it need to remove itself from the `ObjArray` list. I have stated the two methods that I can think of in the first part.

I would like to know if anyone knows of a more efficient way of doing this.

In short:
What's the most efficient way for an item to find/know its position in a list

Comment: I think before we can answer the question we need to understand what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: Why not `ObjArray.remove(object)`?

Comment: More information about your specific use case is necessary, as the question right now is too ambiguous and could only be answered by an ambiguous answer.  As such, my current answer would be:
An object removing itself from a list might be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficient in terms of code:

```
list.remove(this);
```

The object must be given a reference to the list of course.

---

Efficient in terms of performance would require a small redesign, probably involving a Map, but is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: For a 20000 item long list, would the implementation of the "Efficient in terms of performance" be worthwhile? I assume not..

Comment: @Zwander for that many I would use a Map<Integer, MyClass>. But it is unlikely that a user would click on 20000 items...

Answer (score 0):

Usethe List's  indexOf to get the ID.  Drop your idea of an ID for each object._